# AlarmManager triggers when phone is locked

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am setting an alarm with `AlarmManager` to trigger every hour. I don't need to wake up the device, so i'am not using the `WAKEUP` type of alarm.
But i was wondering what happens when the phone is locked for many hours and then, the user unlocks the phone.

Does the `AlarmManager` stacks all the alarms triggered while the phone was locked and send all together when the phone is unlocked?
If yes, is there any way to prevent this and only recive the last one?

Thanks.

Comment: If you use the same ID with each notification then they should override each other instead of stacking.

Comment: The setRepeating operation doesn't ask for an ID. Is there a way to define an ID?

Comment: Oh I was referring to the ID of the Notifications,. I thought from the title that's what you were doing with the alarms.

Comment: Yes, the title was a bit confusing, i already changed it.